# Matplotlib, Consistent font using latex

Tags: matplotlib

My problem is I'd like to use Latex titles in some plots, and no latex in others.  Right now, matplotlib has two different default fonts for Latex titles and non-Latex titles and I'd like the two to be consistent.  Is there an RC setting I have to change that will allow this automatically?

I generate a plot with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

tmpData = np.random.random( 300 )

##Create a plot with a tex title
ax = plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(np.arange(300), tmpData)
plt.title(r'$W_y(\tau, j=3)$')
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), visible = False)

##Create another plot without a tex title
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(np.arange(300), tmpData )
plt.title(r'Some random numbers')
plt.show()
```

Here is the inconsistency I am talking about.  The axis tick labels are thin looking relative to the titles.:
[image]

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611374/sans-serif-font-for-axes-tick-labels-with-latex) will help you

Answer (score 85, accepted):

To make the tex-style/mathtext text look like the regular text, you need to set the mathtext font to Bitstream Vera Sans,

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'custom'
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.rm'] = 'Bitstream Vera Sans'
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.it'] = 'Bitstream Vera Sans:italic'
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.bf'] = 'Bitstream Vera Sans:bold'
matplotlib.pyplot.title(r'ABC123 vs $\mathrm{ABC123}^{123}$')
```

If you want the regular text to look like the mathtext text, you can change everything to Stix. This will affect labels, titles, ticks, etc.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'STIXGeneral'
matplotlib.pyplot.title(r'ABC123 vs $\mathrm{ABC123}^{123}$')
```

Basic idea is that you need to set both the regular and mathtext fonts to be the same, and the method of doing so is a bit obscure. You can see a list of the custom fonts,

```
sorted([f.name for f in matplotlib.font_manager.fontManager.ttflist])
```

As others mentioned, you can also have Latex render everything for you with one font by setting text.usetex in the rcParams, but that's slow and not entirely necessary.

Comment: Nice job! with the "stix" options it works fine; however the most nice LaTeX result is by changing `matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'stix'` into `matplotlib.rcParams['mathtext.fontset'] = 'cm'`. This is "[computer modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern)" the font of LaTeX. Eventually changing the family into `matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = 'cmu serif'` may work, but in my case I had problem with the minus sign, therefore I changed `'stix'` into `'cm'` but I left `'STIXGeneral'` and it looks nice ;)

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus: Is it possible to use `cm` for x ticks and y ticks by default?

Answer (score 19):

**EDIT**

if you want to change the fonts used by LaTeX inside matplotlib, check out this page

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/usetex.html

one of the examples there is

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
## for Palatino and other serif fonts use:
#rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Just pick your favorite!

And if you want a bold font, you can try `\mathbf`

```
plt.title(r'$\mathbf{W_y(\tau, j=3)}$')
```

**EDIT 2**

The following will make bold font default for you

```
font = {'family' : 'monospace',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 22}

rc('font', **font)
```

Comment: I think I should clarify my question.  Right now, I think the Latex font is the uglier one and I'd like to bring it in line with the non-latex font.  I'd like something thicker so my plot text is still readable if the plots are shrunk down and put in a thesis/publication.

Comment: Another clarification.  I want the axis labels made thicker.  They're the most unreadable part of the graph.  I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: @ncRubert the `rc` settings are global, it'll affect all the fonts in the plot.

Comment: Is there an automatic way to make the axis tick labels default to bold face?  I want to make the labels taller, wider, and the individual characters thicker.

Comment: You should increase font size if the plot are shrunk so that they are consistent with your text.
Admitedly, matplotlib can make this cumbersome.

Comment: I get `RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
'lp'`. Do I need to install LaTeX first on my machine (OSX)?