# Sans-serif Font for Axes Tick-labels with Latex

Tags: python, latex, matplotlib

I'm trying to use Latex with matplotlib for the first time. It seems that when using Latex matplotlib uses a serif font for the axes labels. I tried explicitly setting the font-family to 'sans-serif' using

```
rc('font',family='sans-serif')
```

but this had no effect, I'm assuming this is because the axes-labels are inside a math-environment. Is there a way to set the 'rc' so that matplotlib will use a sans-serif font for the axes labels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sans-serif math fonts can be used in LaTeX with the help of the [sfmath](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sfmath) package. To use this package in matplotlib, you need to alter the LaTeX preamble it uses to compile text, which can be done through the 'text.latex.preamble' rc option. Hence,

```
rc('text.latex', preamble='\usepackage{sfmath}')
```

should do what you want. You can also choose another font and supply it as an option to the package, see [sfmath's documentation](http://dtrx.de/od/tex/sfmath.html) for reference.

Comment: Works great! However, my ipython complained about a unicode escape character being used ('\u'). My solution is tom mahe it a raw string:

`rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{sfmath}')`

Comment: Very nice. I was searching all over matplotlib docs and here for almost one hour w/o success. But this works like a charm! +1