# Latex text renders badly in matplotlib plot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, latex, rendering

I have a script to generate a plot both shown in the screen and saved as png. I have set the rc parameters to render Latex text on labels, titles and tick labels as follows:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)
rc('font', family='serif')
```

I run the script and I get no errors, no messages, nothing, but it does look awful (image attached). 
Any ideas what the problem may be?

[image]Running this on MacOX El Capitan with python 2.7 and pdfeTeX 3.141592-1.30.4-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.5)

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried changing the font that is used, e.g. like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367736/matplotlib-consistent-font-using-latex)?

Comment: Hi!! Thank s a lot for the idea but it doesn't work. I don't have mixed normal and tex text in my plots...just want all text to look like latex. I have also tried changing backends but nothing works...