# Make LaTeX math font same as axis labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the following `rcParams` to change the math font for the axis label to the default font by Matplotlib:

```
plt.rcParams.update({'mathtext.default': 'regular'})
```

The label for the y-axis on the left side of the figure below was generated with a LaTeX math expression:

```
plt.ylabel('Concentration ($mol/m^3$)')
```

The label for the y-axis on the right side of the image was generated from a standard label declaration:

```
plt.ylabel('Concentration (mol/m^3)')
```

As you can see in the figure, when LaTeX is used in the `ylabel` string, the displayed font is different than the regular label font.

[image]

How can I make labels created with LaTeX math expressions use the default Matplotlib font?

Comment: [theres a separate stack exchange site for this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I have problems understanding which case is which. Especially as there is no Latex in the question. Why don't you create a [mcve] for both cases.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I updated the question to hopefully clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: So, there is no Latex involved; there is only mathtext present. The issue seems only present in matplotlib versions below version 2. Unfortunately, I do not have an old version here, so I cannot test it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27697390/1168043) should work for you.