# Size of LaTeX symbols on axes labels of a Python plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following minimal working example of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v=[2,2.5,3]
frec=[5,5.5,6]
pl.plot(frec, v, 'ro', markersize=6)
pl.xlabel(u'Wave frequency 'r'$\nu$'u' (Hz)', fontsize=17)
pl.ylabel(u'Phase velocity'r'$v$'u' (cm/s)', fontsize=17)
pl.xlim()
pl.xlim(4.8,6.2)
pl.ylim(1.8,3.2)
pl.show()
```

But when the plot is generated, the LaTeX code included on the labels is too small and does not fit well at all with the rest of the text. Is there any way to make it look better?

The result looks like this, where the greek letters are too small:

[image][Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLuFp.jpg)

Comment: Can you maybe show a picture of what you mean. When running the code it looks like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2P6V.png), where I cannot see any issue with size.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Of course, I'll edit it in a minute.

Comment: You're using an old version of matplotlib. In that case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367736/matplotlib-consistent-font-using-latex)'s accepted answer would be what you're looking for. Alternatively, you may update matplotlib.